# How to display the same field with various nodes in the same row using Views?

Tags: 7, views

How do I do something similar in Views with the below SQL query?

```
select nid,
title AS title1,
type AS node_type,
(select title from node,
field_data_field_node_reference_id
where
node.nid = field_data_field_node_reference_id.field_node_reference_id_target_id
AND
field_data_field_node_reference_id.entity_id = 1)
AS title2,
(select nid from node,
field_data_field_node_reference_id
where
node.nid = field_data_field_node_reference_id.field_node_reference_id_target_id
AND
field_data_field_node_reference_id.entity_id = 1)
AS nid2
from node
where nid=1;
```

The output in MySQL would be:

```
nid | title1     | node_type |   title2        | nid2
1   | Some Title | MyNode    |   Another Title | 69
```

As you can see, they share a relationship by a field called 'field_node_reference_id_target_id'.  Both values, 'title1' and 'title2', are from the *same* table called 'node'.  I would like to avoid writing my own SQL queries, so is there a way to get views to display a similar output (e.g. node titles in the same row that share a relationship)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, simply

1. Add the field relationship your View
2. Add the required fields to the view
3. On the relevant field configuration form, select the relationship to use.

For example:

- "Title" ( no relationship ) to select from base table and
- "Title" ( with relationship ) to select from related data.

Comment: Wow! I did not realize you could use the same field multiple times.  This worked perfectly. THANK YOU!